# Database operation in one go (one transcation)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, service, dao, transactional

I am working on a `driver-booking` management system.
What I want to do is that I need to add a `driver` in `booking table` (which means assigning a booking to driver). Before that I need to check whether or not booking record has driver record associated with or not (booking is assigned or not), If yes then do nothing.

It works fine with one user doing this.
But issue comes with multiple users doing this on `same record, same time`.

How to handle this situation.
I know about `@transactional` **annotation**. Is that the right solution?
Should I apply this on single method rather than on my `booking Assigning Service`?

Using `sync block` would slow down processing alot, so currently I am  against this option

Answer (score 2):

Optimistic locking ssumes that multiple transactions can complete without affecting each other, and that therefore transactions can proceed without locking the data resources that they affect. Before committing, each transaction verifies that no other transaction has modified its data. If the check reveals conflicting modifications, the committing transaction rolls back[1].

With the help of optimistic lock you can handle your problem. Hibernate provide way to implement this.